# Exception unhandled, connecting to MySql in c#?

Tags: c#, mysql

Hello lovely people of the stack,

I get an exception unhandled message:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'System.Security.Permissions, Version=4.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'. The system cannot find the file specified.'

The code:

```
private static string connectionString = @"Server=localhost; Port=100; Database=mmo_db; Uid=root; Pwd=;";
private static void StartDatabase() {
  // MySQL Connection
  try {
    mysqlCon = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
    mysqlCon.Open();
    Console.WriteLine("Connecting to MySQL databaase...");
  }
  catch (MySqlException e) {
    Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", e.ToString());
    if (mysqlCon != null)
      mysqlCon.Close();
    Console.WriteLine("Server will now shutdown. Press any key to continue...");
    Console.ReadLine();
    Environment.Exit(0);
  }
  finally {
    Console.WriteLine("MySQL successfully connected. (Version {0})", mysqlCon.ServerVersion);
    while (true) {}
  }
}
```

The exception unhandled message:*

[image]

Being a little green around the ears I don't understand what is wrong with the code, any help is greatly appreciated!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not related to the question, but you should know it's poor practice to create and open a single shared connection for use throughout an app. It breaks connection pooling and creates performance bottlenecks.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I'm learning so all help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: How did you add the reference to MySql.Data ? Did you use NuGet packages ?

Comment: @A.Baudouin I added a reference in dependencies to MySql.Data.dll located in **C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Installer for Windows\MySql.Data.dll**

Is this incorrect?

Comment: You should NuGet packages, it will add all dependencies automatically and your error will disappear I think

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you didn't provide the correct credentials in the connection string to access the database.

Try providing the password in the connection string as your pwd seems to be empty?

Comment: Bad credentials would give a different error, and omitting the password from a public post is common practice.